# Using a Shared Array in multiprocessing to save values

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm  attempting to get python multiprocessing working to speed up a code I've written. The code looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Array, Pool
import numpy as np
#setting up shared memory array
global misfit
misfit = Array('d', np.empty((dim1,dim2,dim3,dim4)).flat)

#looping through some values
for i in xrange(0,1):
     #setting up pool
     pool = Pool()
     p = [pool.apply_async(self.testfunc,args=(somevals,j)) for j in xrange(0,1)]
     pool.close()
     pool.join()
```

Where self.testfunc looks like:

```
 def testfunc(self,somevals,j):
      #some calculations
      for k in xrange(0,1):
           #some calculations
           for mn in xrange(0,1):
                 #some more calculations
                 #save results
                 result = i*j*k*mn # example
                 misfit[i*j*k*mn] = result
```

My problem is that when I run this none of the values are saved in the shared Array, and it remains empty. I understand this could be to do with the global variable, but in a simpler program that uses this exact setup, the values are saved to the array. The array is quite large in the full program as well (4561920000 values). Also if I call this function outside of the Pool, it works and the values are saved.

So my question is what I am doing wrong here? Am I sending the shared Array incorrectly?

EDIT: Figured I'd add in the code that works:

```
from multiprocessing import Array, Pool
from numpy import empty, sin
from time import time
import numpy as np

def initarr():
  a = Array('d', empty((5, 50, 80)).flat)
  return a

def testfunc(i, j, k):
  count = (i*50*80) + (j*80) + k
  x = sin(k)
  a[count] = x
  y = np.fft.fft(np.exp(2j*np.pi*np.arange(50000)/50000))


def process(i):
  start = time()
  pool = Pool()
  for j in xrange(0, 50):
    p = [pool.apply_async(testfunc, args=(i, j, k)) for k in xrange(0, 80)]
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
  print time() - start


global a
a = initarr()

for i in xrange(0, 5):
   process(i)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so with the help of someone from our IT department, I finally have a version of this that works, so for anybody in the future viewing this question, I'll post a solution. I haven't really used stack overflow much so sorry if it's bad etiquette to answer my own question.

We got this working using an initializer function, but we had to make sure the initializer function was in the **same file (module)** as the function being run by the Pool. So in one module (misc) we had:

```
**misc.py**
def testfunc(self,somevals,j):
  #some calculations
  for k in xrange(0,len(krange)):
       #some calculations
       for mn in xrange(0,len(mnrange)):
             #some more calculations
             #save results
             loc = (i*len(jrange)*len(krange)*len(mnrange))+
                   (j*len(krange)*len(mnrange))+(k*len(mnrange))+mn
             result = i*j*k*mn # example
             misfit[loc] = result

def initpool(a):
    global misfit
    misfit = a
```

And in the main file we have:

```
**main.py**
from multiprocessing import Array, Pool
from misc import initpool, testfunc
import numpy as np

#setting up shared memory array
misfit = Array('d', np.empty((dim1,dim2,dim3,dim4)).flat)

#looping through some values
for i in xrange(0,len(irange)):
     #setting up pool
     pool = Pool(initializer=initpool,initargs=(misfit,),processes=20)
     p = [pool.apply_async(testfunc,args=(somevals,j)) for j in xrange(0,len(jrange))]
     pool.close()
     pool.join()

print(misfit[0])
```

**Note that** when we initially set up the Array, it must be named the **same** as the variable you set in initpool, at least from when I tested it.

This probably isn't the best way to do it but it works and hopefully some other people might find a use for it!